# Algorithm for 2D not quite Delaunay triangulation

Tags: python, algorithm, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying to write an algorithm to do a triangulation on a 2D sampling of grid points. The idea is similar to Delaunay triangulation but with a few custom rules.

To represent the vertices and their coordinates, the input is a sparse 2D array of 0's and 1's. A given element is 1 if it is a vertex, and 0 if it is not. So basically if it is 1, it means that point was sampled and the triangulation needs to include it in the triangulation; if it is a 0, it should not be involved in the triangulation.

1) Unlike Delaunay, in my case, all the triangles must be right triangles with horizontal or vertical orientation, e.g.:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

has a right triangle that can be formed by connecting the 1's. And it has a vertical/horizontal orientation since the 2 non-hypotenuse edges are horizontal and vertical.

2) No 2 triangles can share a hypotenuse, but it's ok if they share an edge that is not a hypotenuse.

3) No vertex can be the apex of a right triangle and also a non-apex of a different right triangle. In other words,

```
0  1  0 
0 (1) 1
0  1  0
```

is ok because the central a marked inside a (), is the apex of both right triangles.
But in the following case:

```
0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 0 1 1
```

it would ok to do:

```
0 0 0 X B
A 0 0 A B
```

meaning 2 triangles (AAX and BBX), but the following would not be allowed:

```
0 0 0 A B
A 0 0 X B
```

since now the vertex "X" would be an apex in triangle A, but would be a non-apex in triangle B.

I'm interested in any thoughts / outline for how to develop this algorithm. The matrices are pretty big, but very sparse, so the algorithm doesn't have to be too efficient; any conceptually simple approach should work fine. The output should be a list of lists:

```
[[(x1a,y1a),(x1b,y1b),(x1c,y1c)], [(x2a,y2a),(x2b,y2b),(x2c,y2c)], ..., [(xNa,yNa),(xNb,yNb),(xNc,yNc)]]
```

for the coordinates of the 3 vertices of all of the N different triangles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496589/finding-right-triangle-coordinates-in-binary-array